# set curect address to <form action=">

Tags: wordpress

i create simple plugin wordpress , one validationform.php and rflinsertdb.php
when user click on submit form , i want got rflinsertdb.php the page validation and insert information to db , but wordpress give me Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
this 2 php page in one folder that name in public ,i see to many codes in internet but not help,  how can i do that ?
thx alot 
i try this codes for action form

```
<form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/rflInsertdb.php">
    <p id="errorMessage"></p>

    <p>name: <input type="text" class="register" name="name" id="name"></p>

    <p>family: <input type="text" class="registerForm" id="family" name="family"></p>

    <p>numbers :<input type="number" class="registerForm" id="numbers" name="numbers" min="1" max="200" value="1"></p>

    <p>tell: <input type="text" class="registerForm" id="tell" name="tell"></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="ثبت" class="registerForm" id="submit" name="submit"></p>

</form>
```

Comment: And are your `rflInsertdb.php` is under the template path, or under the plugin path?

Comment: both of them into the , wp-content ,-> plugin-> , rdf-> public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to you, because you are using template directory for: `/rflInsertdb.php`

Try to use

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>/rflInsertdb.php">
```

If your file is under the public (what is under the plugin dir), then maybe:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>/public/rflInsertdb.php">
```

See here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url